# Weird buffering with prompt in haskell

Tags: haskell

I was playing around in Haskell and noticed something weird. I've defined a simple prompt function below.

```
-- file: test.hs
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . ("Hello, " ++) =<< (putStr "Name: " >> getLine)
```

When I `runhaskell` this, it works as expected, printing the prompt, waits for my input, then prints the greeting.

```
$ runhaskell test.hs
Name: kwarrtz
Hello, kwarrtz
```

When I compile it, however, things get weird. When I run it, it doesn't print the prompt, instead giving me a blank line and waiting for input. When I type my name and hit enter, it prints the prompt and the greeting, on the same line. In otherwords, the `getLine` happens before the `putStr`.

```
$ ghc test.hs
$ ./test
kwarrtz
Name: Hello, kwarrtz
```

Any thoughts on what's happening? I imagine it has something to do with the line buffering on my terminal, but I'm not sure how (that or I've just made some really ridiculous mistake in my code).

I'm running GHC 7.8.3 on Mac OS X El Capitan and using the default Terminal app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buffering.

```
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

I think you can get all that from `System.IO`

Comment: To expand a little: as in some other languages, output is buffered, and is not really sent to the OS until a newline, or an explicit flush operation happens. (It is sad though, that `runhaskell` and compiling the code use different buffering -- they should be more consistent IMHO)

Comment: @chi Is there are reason that `runhaskell` and `ghc` use different buffering modes, or is it just an unintentional inconsistency?

Comment: @Kwarrtz I can't think of any reason.